# Como guardar valor de checkbox por registro de base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, array, checkbox

Hola estoy haciendo un sistema de registro de asistencia de alumnos , donde aparece la fecha y la asignatura a asignar la asistencia , de esta forma cuando el usuario presione buscar insertara en la tabla asistencia los alumnos la fecha, la asignatura, el curso, etc los id en este caso y un estado en  0 que es un checkbox para poner presente(1) o ausente(0). Entonces ahora el usuario puede enviar la asistencia e ir marcando los checkbox , al presionar el boton enviar asistencia  se envia al controlador donde se deberian actualizar los registros que vienen con checkbox 1, el problema es que lo hace , pero si no esta checkeado algun alumno deberia quedar en 0 y no actualizarse el registro pero se me actualizan todos a 1. he intendando muchas cosas y todavia no logro dar con el resultado esperado adjunto codigo de vista, controlador e interfaz.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 <table class="table col-12 table-bordered table-hover mt-2">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
          <th scope="col">Apellidos</th>
          <th scope="col">Rut</th>
          <th scope="col"><button type="button" class="btn btn-link check-all">Seleccionar todos</button></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      @foreach($alumnos as $alumno)
        <tr>
          <td>{{ $alumno->nombre }}</td>
          <td>{{ $alumno->apellidos}}</td>
          <td>{{ $alumno->rut}}</td>
        </a>
          <td>
          <div class="form-check">
          <input type="checkbox" name="asistencia[]" value="{{$alumno->estado}}"<?php echo ($alumno->estado == 1 ? ' checked' : '')?> class="form-check-input settings" id="checkAsistencia">      
          <input type="hidden" value="{{$idCursoActual}}" name="idCurso">
  </div>
          </td>
          </tr>
   

     public function enviarAsistencia(Request $request, $idCurso){

        $idAlumno=$request->idAlumno;
        $checkBoxs = $request->asistencia;
        $alumnos = $request->alumno;
        $idCurso= $request->idCurso;
        $asistencia = Asistencia::find($request->asistenciaId);

      $count = count($checkBoxs);

      $estado = 1;

      for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {

        foreach($asistencia as $registroAsistencia){
            
        $registroAsistencia->estado = $estado;
        $registroAsistencia->save();
        }
      }

    return back()->with('Listo','Ingresado correctamente');
    }
```

Alguna sugerencia de como hacerlo llevo muchos dias sin poder realizarlo probando de distintas formas.
Agredesco sus respuestas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public function enviarAsistencia(Request $request, $idCurso){

    //estado de la asistencia , es el checkbox 1 presente 0 ausente
    $estadoAsistencia = $request->asistencia;

    //id de la asistencia del alumno
    $asistenciaId = $request->asistenciaId;

    
    foreach($asistenciaId as $index => $id) {

        $asistencia = Asistencia::find($id);
        $estado = (isset($estadoAsistencia[$index])) ? 1 : 0;   
        $asistencia->estado = $estado;
        $asistencia->save();
        
        
    }

return back()->with('Listo','Ingresado correctamente');
}
```

codigo corregido

He corregido el codigo me funciona registrar la asistencia y todo pero al momento de por ejemplo editar una asistencia es decir entrar y quitar la seleccion de un alumno para que quede ausente por ejemplo el primer alumno, envio la asistencia, y se me guarda como que el que falto fue el ultimo y no el primero que seleccione, hago un dump para ver que vienen en los checkbox y efectivamente en vez de venir el 2 (que es que no asistio) en el primer alumno viene el 2 en el ultimo, que podria estar fallando?

Comment: A todos los registros estás asignando `$estado` y la variable siempre tiene valor 1. Si el orden en que vienen los _checkbox_ es el mismo de los registros, prueba con: `$registroAsistencia->estado = (isset($checkBoxs[$i])) ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, edite mi pregunta y agregue una imagen de la consola donde se ve el estado que lleva el registro en este caso uno solo esta en 1 y los otros en 0 y tambien se ve el id del registro que corresponde es decir la asistencia, hice lo que me comentas , que me parece bien pero me tira el siguiente error:

Attempt to assign property 'estado' of non-object

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas incluir todos los datos necesarios al generar la lista de asistencia, por ejemplo, falta id de alumno o asistencia. No es necesario tener `idCurso` en cada fila, porque siempre es el mismo y basta que aparezca una sola vez.

```
<table class="table col-12 table-bordered table-hover mt-2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
      <th scope="col">Apellidos</th>
      <th scope="col">Rut</th>
      <th scope="col">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-link check-all">Seleccionar todos</button>
          <input type="hidden" name="idCurso" value="{{$idCursoActual}}">
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  @foreach($alumnos as $alumno)
    <tr>
      <td>{{ $alumno->nombre }}</td>
      <td>{{ $alumno->apellidos}}</td>
      <td>{{ $alumno->rut}}</td>
    </a>
      <td>
      <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" name="asistencia[]" value="{{$alumno->estado}}"<?php echo ($alumno->estado == 1 ? ' checked' : '')?> class="form-check-input settings" id="checkAsistencia">
      <?php // Agregar ID de asistencia, como arreglo ?>
      <input type="hidden" name="asistenciaId[]" value="{{$alumno->asistenciaId}}">
```

En PHP vas a recibir los siguientes valores:

- idCurso: Un solo valor
- asistenciaId: Arreglo con ID de asistencia para cada elemento mostrado
- asistencia: **Esto es muy importante:** Arreglo solo con los *checkbox* marcados, pero manteniendo los mismos índices que *asistenciaId*

El proceso sería recorrer el arreglo de alumnos para obtener asistencias y guardar:

```
    $asistenciaId = $request->asistenciaId; // Es un arreglo
    $asistencia = $request->asistencia; // También es arreglo
    $idCurso= $request->idCurso;

    // Recorrer arreglo asistenciaId por índice y valor
    foreach($asistenciaId as $index => $id) {
        // Asistencia solo si se marcó el checkbox
        $estado = (isset($asistencia[$index])) ? 1 : 0;
        // Aquí debes crear la consulta para ACTUALIZAR por
        // asistenciaId = $id
        // Solo guardas el estado (0 o 1)
    }
```

Comment: Estimado muchas gracias por tus respuestas, me has orientado un monton, el tema es que esta parte no es para insertar, si no para modificar , es decir modificar una asistencia que ya esta en la base de datos,

por eso agrego este hidden en la vista  <input type="hidden" name="asistenciaId" value="{{$alumno->asistenciaId}}">
 el cual me sirve para tomar el id de la asistencia como tal, esta tabla contiene el id de la asistencia, estado,id_alumno,id_curso,id_periodo,id_asignatura,fecha.

Comment: Por eso al mandar al controlador debe tomar los checkbox que vienen con el id de la asistencia , para que si el checkbox esta marcado pasar 1 y modificar la asistencia, luego si el otro registro es 0 modificar el estado de esa asistencia a 0 no se si se entiende.

Comment: A fin de cuentas el proceso es el mismo, solo usa _asistenciaId_ para actualizar. La variable `$estado` ya tiene 1 si se marcó el checkbox y cero si no.

Comment: amigo muchas gracias, no habia entendido antes jaja tenias razon, me ha funcionado, pero tengo un leve error , que no se a que se debe , por ejemplo quiero poner ausente el primer registro, envio la asistencia y se modifica el ultimo, asi me quedo el codigo en el controller

Comment: Deje el codigo como me quedo el controller en la edición de la pregunta

Comment: no se que pasa pero cuando deselecciono el primer checkbox y dejo los demas chekeados si hago un dump($estado) deberia llegarme 0 1 1 1 , pero me llega mal, me llega 1 1 1 0 , por lo que al enviar  la asistencia se hace el update incorrectamente,no se que puede estar pasando e tratado de corregirlo pero no se cual es el error.